# jsfiddle set-up with angular resource

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I have a strange issue setting up a jsfiddle. I have tried adding an Angular library but it doesn't seem to work in mine.

[Mine- Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/xm1q9on9/2/)

[example working](http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/tcVhN/)

Any thoughts?

(code below compulsory but not the issue as identical for both)

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Sally';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set `ng-app`. In version 1.0.5 it was not yet required, but since somewhere 1.2.x you have to set it .

try this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    Hello {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you want to check out this one [tab issue with ui-bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867303/ui-bootstrap-angular-filter-in-tab-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the two JSFiddles are the body tag.

The working one: `<body ng-app="app">`
Yours: `<body>`

You can add your custom body tag in the Fiddle Options section.

This image is taken from the working one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IN JS Fiddle, Check "Fiddle Options" in left panel , Open it , you will find input box called body tag, Copy the below code and paste it to body tag input box..

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

Thats it..