# ui-bootstrap angular filter in tab conflict

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-tabset

I have an issue with a filter when inside a tabset.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('myModule').controller('ModalController', function($scope) {
$scope.favsLib = [1, 19];
$scope.docsLib = [{
    "id": 19
}, {
    "id": 23
}];
$scope.checkboxDoc = false;
$scope.favFilter = function (docsLib) {
    if ($scope.favsLib.length > 0 && $scope.checkboxDoc == true) {
        if ($.inArray(docsLib.id, $scope.favsLib) < 0) return;
    }

    return docsLib;
}
});
angular.module('myModule').directive('tabDirective', function() {
return {
    scope: {
        display: '='
    },
    controller: "ModalController",
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

    }
};


});
```

here is the html I would like:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ModalController">
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Documents">
      <tab-directive display="docsLib">  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxDoc">favourites
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="doc in docsLib | filter:favFilter">{{doc}}</li>
    </ul>
   </tab-directive>
    </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

If I take the the input box outside of the tabset the filter works fine:

[Working outside tabset - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xm1q9on9/12/)

clicking on checkbox filters results correctly.

But placing the input inside the tabset doesn't work, so there maybe an issue with the ui-bootstrap.

Has anyone any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the scope hierarchy, will post an answer soon. EDIT: or maybe not since @Capricorn ha already posted a (correct) answer in the meantime. BTW, an alternative to using an object would be to use the `controllerAs` sytnax and attaching the `checkboxDoc` directly to the controller instance, avoiding the pitfals with scope prototypical inheritance and attribute shadowing.

Comment: BTW, if you want a detailed explanation on what is happening behind the scenes, see [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no issue about ui-bootstrap, but about scoping.

When placing the checkbox inside the tabstrip, the *checkboxDoc* property is placed at the inner scope (the scope created by the tabstrip directive).
However the property used for filtering your list in placed at the outer scope (the controller scope).

Quick and dirty fix would be to place the checkbox inside the tabstrip, but change the model to `ng-model="$parent.checkboxDoc"`.

The proper way is, to not put a primitive at the scope but an object. So instead of using `$scope.checkboxDoc = false`, assign `$scope.checkboxDoc = {checked: false);`. The you can properly read/write the parent/outer/controller scope property by assigning `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxDoc.checked">`

See you corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xm1q9on9/14/

Somewhere i once read, that the `ng-model` attribute should always contain at least one dot, like `object.property`. This mnemonic helps to never assign primitive properties to the scope object directly and would have fixed that probpem. Read more about scoping at the [official angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) or for even more details at the [angularJS Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: RE: "should contain a dot" - this is true, but a more modern pattern is to use the `controllerAs` syntax and attach the properties directly to the controller instance. This avoids both the hidden pitfalls with the scope hierarchy, and also makes it explicit where a particular variable is coming from. Just my 2 ¢

Comment: Thank you, that was really causing me a lot of problems.